# Configure SonarQube Eclipse plugin to visualize the results of analysis from Sonar plugin on Jenkins

Tags: eclipse, jenkins, sonarqube

I have a question regarding the setup and configuration of SonarQube plugin in Eclipse . We have Sonar plugin version 2.1 installed in Jenkins. It runs analysis every day and  I want to configure the Eclipse plugin so that it displays the result from the Jenkins analysis. I don't know if this is possible because I can't find any information about this, the only hope comes from the first answer of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20005196/sonarqube-how-is-it-used/21728229#21728229).

PS. I apologize if there already is an answer to my question, I couldn't find it.

Comment: Have you looked at http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/hudsonjenkins-mylyn-builds-connector#.U2n1labh-O0 ? I just tried installing it but it didn't seem to work for me, but will give it a more serious go later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Sonarqube eclipse plugin is able to present to you the results of your analysis you run with jenkins. The results your are looking for however, are stored in the sonarqube database. So you need to to configure the sonarqube eclipse plugin to connect to the sonarqube-server, not the jenkins-server.

Here is how you do the configuration:
http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Configuring+SonarQube+in+Eclipse